# Intuitionistic well-orderings of uncountable sets

Tags: constructive-mathematics, well-orders, intuitionistic-logic

The well-ordering principle has always been considered to be highly unconstructive, as far as I know. However, I think intuitionistic mathematics can be compatible with the existence of a well-ordering of $\mathcal N = \{ \alpha : \mathbb N \to \mathbb N \}$ (or other uncountable sets like $\mathbb R$), which Brouwer and others did not seem to accept.

I know that a full, positive version of well-ordering would imply some omniscience principle, so let's begin with a weaker property for orderings $<$ on a set $X$ that are total in the sense $$\lnot (\lnot x = y \land \lnot x \lt y \land \lnot y \lt x).$$ Let's call it a well-ordering if

$$
WO(<) \equiv \lnot (\exists f : \mathbb N \to X) (\forall n) (f(n+1)  < f(n)).$$
(This is probably not the most efficient principle, just note that it can't be the usual positive one)

**Question**: is the principle that $\mathcal N$ can be well-ordered consistent with the principles of intuitionistic analysis? (continuity principle and bar theorem or Church thesis)

---

I'll now show my argument that says that Brouwer could have accepted this principle, unless of course there's a serious issue.

I begin with any element of $\mathcal N$. Every time I construct a proof that an element $\alpha \in \mathcal N$ is distinct from all the previous elements, I add it to the end (i.e., postulate $\beta < \alpha$ for every previous $\beta$).

I might instead come up with a whole sequence $\{\alpha_n\} \subseteq \mathcal N$ and a proof that no $\alpha_n$ has appeared previously. Then I add the whole sequence at the end (i.e., I postulate $\beta < \alpha_0 < \alpha_1 < \dots < \alpha_n < \dots$ for all previous $\beta$).

Now, it might appear that diagonalization would lead to problems. But diagonalization is just a particular way of constructing a new $\alpha$ that has not previously appeared.

A similar objection is that the resulting order type would be $\omega^2$, and thus the order isomorphism $\omega^2 \to \mathcal N$ would allow further diagonalization, contradicting totality. However, this surveyable ordinal has certain positive properties (like trichotomy), that prevent the construction isomorphism.

Note that every new element that I construct will immediately be compared with all the previously constructed elements. Thus the resulting ordering possibly has the desired properties (including $WO$).

---

A simpler approach is to consider an uncountable subset of $\mathbb N$ with the usual order relation, I think it has the properties $WO$ and trichotomy, but such a subset must be undecidable. The details likely will depend on the specific subset.

---

**Summing up**: I don't understand why the well-ordering principle for uncountable sets is necessarily not constructive. But I haven't been able to find a source that claims otherwise.

Perhaps the negative versions of well-ordering are of very limited use, and that's why they are not discussed? Or are they inconsistent with certain constructive principles?

Comment: "well-order" requires that every non-empty subset has a smallest element. How shall we achieve this in the reals ? The usual order of course does not work since the set of real numbers greater than $0$ has no smallest element.

Comment: @Peter I've defined one above for a similar uncountable set. The real line is understood in an intuitionistic way here, never finished. So until I construct an element that I prove different from all the previously constructed elements, I cannot say that such an element exists

Comment: I get the feeling that pretty much the same approach could be used to build "axiom of choice for setoids" at least if the indexing setoid has decidable equality: internally keep a table of values you've returned so far, and each time you're called with a new input, use the constructive existence proof to extract a value to return and register it in the table.  (Where "axiom of choice for setoids" includes for example constructing a *respectful* section of the projection $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} / \mathbb{Q}$ which can then be used to construct a nonmeasurable set.)

Comment: Maybe one objection to the approach is that an implementation would internally involve something like a call-with-current-continuation; but that can also be used to build a "decide truth of each proposition" a la the "devil's bargain" description: you always return false at first with the proof being a synthetic function, and if that function is ever called, you rewind execution to the original call and return true with the proof given as an argument of the synthetic function.

Comment: The problem being: even though technically that can always "fix up" answers in such a way that it eventually defeats any contradictions you try to use to poke holes in the facade (or it eventually proves a contradiction in the original axioms), it's also 100% useless: if it returned false, you don't know whether that's actually "the correct answer" even in a Platonic classical universe.

Comment: Also, the results of your process, or of my "axiom of choice" progress, could very well depend on the order you call the result functions in.  That makes the semantics a lot more difficult to work with; for example, if you call the overall function twice with the same inputs, then the results can end up being different if you call the two result functions differently.  That breaks the assumption you would usually want to make that $f(x) = f(x)$.

Comment: @DanielSchepler Thanks for the comments. I think I see the connection with setoid choice, as formalized [here](https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Logic.SetoidChoice.html#x':12) for example (for decidable $R$). The problem I thought would appear is that infinitely many values should be added to the table at the same time if you prove that they are all new, but actually you don't have to introduce them at once, only whenever a particular value must be computed. Clearly it's dependent on the order of computation as you say. However it doesn't have all the power of call by continuation, I think

Comment: I've also realised that the argument that infinite sequences can be treated element by element works for my well ordering too, and relates it to subcountability. A natural principle would then be the existence of  an injective $\mathbb N \to \mathbb R$ that misses no real number (a negative version of surjectivity). Then you can push forward the ordering of the naturals to the reals. Of course this is stronger than my original axiom, so it's subject to the same objections (in case it's even consistent)

Comment: I don't understand, however, what your respectful projection $\mathbb R \to \mathbb R / \mathbb Q$ means. Isn't the nontrivial part to choose a representative, that is, an extensional function $\mathbb R/ \mathbb Q \to \mathbb R$?

Comment: Well, of course every total function $\mathbb N \to \mathbb R$ misses some number, I'll think tomorrow how to solve that issue...

Comment: @DanielSchepler I'm slightly confused by your first comment. Choice for decidable setoids doesn't allow you to build a section of the map $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} /\mathbb{Q}$ because $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Q}$ doesn't have decidable equality, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this principle is indeed consistent with bar induction and the continuity principle. It is separately consistent with Church’s Thesis.

Consider the following:

> Weak Church’s Thesis: For all functions $f : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$, it is not not the case that $f$ is computable.

This principle is indeed consistent with bar induction and continuity. It is also obviously consistent with Church’s Thesis. Finally, it implies that $\mathcal{N}$ can be “well-ordered” in your sense.

Assume Weak Church’s Thesis.

We say a natural number $n$ represents a function $f : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ if $n$ is the index of the computable function $f$ (using a canonical enumeration of the partial computable functions, eg with Kleene’s T predicate). Write this as $R(n, f)$. The above principle states $\forall f \neg \neg \exists n (R(n, f))$.

Now recall the following constructive theorem:

> Suppose there exists $n$ such that $P(n)$. Then it is not not the case that there is a least $n$ such that $P(n)$.

The proof of the above is by induction.

We say that $n$ is the canonical representative of $f$ if $n$ is the smallest $n$ such that $R(n, f)$. Write this as $CR(n, f)$. Then we have $\forall f \neg \neg \exists n (CR(n, f))$.

We are now ready to define our “well-order” on $\mathcal{N}$. We say $f < g$ if and only if $\exists n \exists m (n < m \land CR(n, f) \land CR(m, g))$.

It’s straightforward to show that $<$ is irreflexive and transitive. It’s also straightforward to show it is a “well-ordering”. For if we have a function $h : \mathbb{N} \to \mathcal{N}$ such that $\forall n (h(n + 1) < h(n))$, then each $h(n)$ has a canonical representative. Define $g(n)$ to be the canonical representative of $h(n)$. Then $g : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ is strictly decreasing; contradiction.